# limelight api paging with media method

Tags: php, api

I'm using the limelight content API to retrieve all of my videos.

I used their examples and it is returning all media.
Here is the code:

```
        $request = "http://api.video.limelight.com/rest/organizations/$org_id/media/search";

        $signed_request = LvpAuthUtil::authenticate_request("GET", $request, $access_key, $secret, $params);
```

Now I want to tell it which field to sort the results by. The [documentation](http://support.video.limelight.com/support/docs/content_api/#3.0) says that there are paging parameters available, but I can't seem to get them to work.

I tried adding `$params = array("and" => "sort_by:title");`
and `$params = array("sort_by" => "title");` but neither worked.

I also tried adding it to the url but it didn't work. `http://api.video.limelight.com/rest/organizations/$org_id/media/search?sort_by=title`

Can someone tell me how to pass the paging parameters correctly?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 http://api.video.limelight.com/rest/organizations/6d4242bd0cf94083a0195bfc2083e46e/media.xml?page_id=0&page_size=50&sort_by=publish_date&sort_order=desc
```

Check optional parameter in `List all channels that contain a specific media`

```
Optional Parameters

page_id = <The zero-based identifier of the page to return> 
page_size = <The number of results to return per page> (default/max: 500) 
sort_by = <The field by which the results should be sorted> {publish_date, create_date, update_date} (default: update_date) 
sort_order = <The order in which the results should display> {asc, desc} (default: asc)
```

Comment: please see my updated question. it didn't work when i tried adding it to the url.

Comment: You are passing `$org_id` in url instead use number. Instead http://api.video.limelight.com/rest/organizations/23/media/search?sort_by=title

Comment: The value of $org_id is a number. And it's working to get all media without the 'sort_by', so the $org_id is not the problem.